# Vuex - Form Handling with dynamic Data

Tags: vue.js, vuex

i try to accomplish a filtering mechanism with lots of dynamic loaded filtering-values. Means i get for example `data`

```
[
  {
    key : value
  },
  {
    key : value
  }
]
```

then in my template

```
<md-checkbox 

   @change="change($event)"
   v-for="(value, key, index) in values"
   id="index"
   v-model="some_dynamicly_set_vuex_state"

>{{key}}</md-checkbox>
```

i tried some things like:

```
...
v-model="model(value)"
...

with

computed : {
   model : function(val){
     //error and still no clue how to set the store.state
   }
}
```

and

```
...
v-model="model(value)"
...

with

methods : {
   model : function(val){
     //same error and still no clue how to set the store.state
   }
}
```

i need the models in the store because other components can mutate them.

the problem is that i don't know which key's and how many of them will come so something like the following wouldn't fit

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        key1: false,
        key2 : false,        
    },
    mutations: {}
  }
)
    ...
    v-model="key"
    ...

    with

    computed : {
       key1 : function(){
          return this.$store.state.key1;
       },
       key2 : function(){
          return this.$store.state.key2;
       }
    }
```

EDIT: for better understanding

Imagine i get from an API call many persons with a lot of meta-data like spoken languages, skills etc. In the same API call i get available languages. What i want to do is filtering the persons based on which language they can speak.

But i cannot know how many languages and which languages are coming.

So what i try to do is somehow dynamicly create VUEX States for the checkboxes for each language. Plus i need to create for the same languages a computed variable or so to bind in v-model. And @change i could mutate the vuex-state.

[image: the langauge checkboxes]

EDIT: what i have until now

//using the component

`<filter-checkbox storeKey="language" :values="facets.languages" id_prefix="language_"></filter-checkbox`>

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!--the value in the v-for is just additional data which represents the count of person who can speak the language , just needed to do like this to have th key-->
        <md-checkbox @change="change($event)" v-for="(value, key, index) in values" :id="id_prefix+index" v-model="model">{{key}}</md-checkbox>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default{
        props : ['values','id_prefix','storeKey'],       
        computed : {
            model : function(){  
                //with the key of the v-for              
                return this.$store.state[somehowDynamicly];
            }
        },
        methods : {
            change : function(e){
                this.$store.commit('changeState',{
                    //maybe a dynamicly computed value or something?
                    state : this[somehowDynamicly]
                    value : e
                })
            }
        },
        created : function(){
           //this is not working as in "created"-function props (storeKey) are not available
           this.$store.registerModule(this.storeKey, {
           // ...also somehowDynamicly 
           })      
    }
    }
</script>
```

and then in the global store

```
//maybe this has to go also in the this.$store.registerModule function?
    mutations: {
       changeState ( state, objValues){
       state[objValues.state] = objValues.value;
    }
```

the part with the "this.$store.registerModule" i don't really know how to use it was just a try to solve the part with the dynamicly generated VUEX-states

Comment: I also found this conversation https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1056 at the bottom of the page the comment is looking like a possible way but I don't understand what he is doing and how to adapt to my situation.

Comment: So in general, you're trying to store arbitrary number of states in the store? What's the problem of using an array/object for that?

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 yes ok i didn't know that the keys of an object inside the store are still reactive. let's assume this is working. Still how to pass or generate the models for each language checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly getting what you are trying to achieve and what is the error you are getting. But I noticed following mistakes you are doing in the code you have shared.

1. you have `v-for="(value, key, index) in values"` which is not correct syntax and will not work, you will have to write it like: `v-for="(value, index) in values"` use the hash: `value` as par your requirement. see example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v5ykLmfk/).
2. You have `v-model="some_dynamicly_set_vuex_state"`, which is not possible as you can only change vuex state by a mutation, so instead of vuex state, you can have some other variable and you can have a watcher on that variable, whenever that variable changes, mutate the vuex state.
3. you can not have a computed property which can take a parameter, as you are trying to do in `v-model="model(value)"`, you can do it as methods like you have shown.

If you can create a sample jsfiddle of the thing you are trying to do, and explain the error you are getting, it will be helpful in finding the exact problem.

Comment: v-for="(value, key, index) in values" is working as expected. How would you assign multiple dynamic variables based on the data which is coming from an API call in Vue? i updated my question

Comment: updated again my question as i think jsfiddle can't help as my application is including routes and many states